# python random int append to list and count "x" top numbers that occurred and number of times int occurred

Tags: python, random, count, multiple-occurrence

New to python so all help is appreciated! I did check and found several count post but couldn't find any that print the top occurrences from the list. (ie 3 occurred 6x, 4 occurred 4x and 2 occurred 3x)

**Goal:** I'd like to have the code print 1000 numbers 0,1000 randomly and then be able to choose how many to show.

so for example num = [0,5,12,5, 22,12,0 ,32,22,0,0,5] I want to be able to see say the top 3 repeated numbers and how many times that number occurred.  0-4times, 5-3times, 12-2times.

**code Progression #valid attempts are made**

Prints 1000 times randomly

```py
import random

for x in range(1001):
    print(random.randint(0,1001))
```

Append the randint directly to num

```py
import random

num = []
for x in range(1001):
    num.append(random.randint(0,1001))

print(num)
```

Includes prompt to get how many integers you want to see.

```py
import random

num = []
for x in range(1001):
    num.append(random.randint(0,1001))

highscore = input("Please enter howmany numbers you'd like to see: ")
print("The top", highscore, "repeated numbers are: ", num)
```

**Issues left:** how to print highscore's count for num (this part  0-4times, 5-3times, 12-2times.)

Attempt at count issue (prints 0 every time. added num to print to confirm if "y" was in the list)

```py
import random

#creates list
num = []
for x in range(0,10):
    num.append(random.randint(0,10))

highscore = input("input number of reoccurrence's you want to see: ")
y = num.count(highscore)
print(num, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `most_common` method from `Counter` class in `collections` library. [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

```py
from collections import Counter
import random

number_of_elements = 1000


counter = Counter([random.randint(0,1001) for i in range(number_of_elements)])


# printing 3 most common elements.
print(counter.most_common(3))
```

output:

```
[(131, 6), (600, 5), (354, 5)]
```

This output means the number 131 is the most common and repeated 6 times, then 600 is the second most common and it is repeated 5 times and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to invalid type. Try

```
y = num.count(int(highscore))
```

Then it works fine,

`input number of reoccurrence's you want to see: 4 [5, 4, 0, 6, 0, 2, 7, 9, 3, 1] 1`